# disable listener after onclick listview element : android

Tags: android, listview, toast

I have a list of elements that populate a listview. When I tap once, a request is made to my server, and I show a toast as the tap is made, then another toast when the response has come in. I'd like to disable the listview for clicking while this happens. What's the best way to do it? I tried a simple boolean but somehow it always returned back to its original state before the response from the server had come in. Also tried disabling the layout elements, and wouldn't go. Suggestions?

```
//beginning of my FirstClass
static boolean wait = false;

//...some code

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, arraylist));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(!wait){
                    wait = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Processing...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String URL = "myurl";
                    new RequestTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(URL);
               }
            }
        });
```

and then within my RequestTask class

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(this.context, result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    FirstClass.wait = false; // turn it back to false?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to disable where you have `// start disable` and then disable in your RequestTask.  Request task is probably being executed in the background on a different thread.  This means that your `// end disable?` code would be executed shortly after you create the RequestTask (this is probably why the boolean goes back to enabled before the request finishes).  However, if you passed request task a reference to the boolean you were talking about (through the constructor), you could allow the RequestTask to unlock when its HTTP request completes.

So basically, give the RequestTask a reference to the boolean you're working with and when it's HTTP request completes, set it to enabled.  Alternatively, define a function in your activity `enableListView()` (or maybe `backgroundRequestComplete()`) which actually switches the boolean to enabled.  Then give the RequestTask a reference to your activity and have it call the enableListView() method upon completion.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense but I should be able to do this without a reference to my boolean within the RequestTask no? I added some code to show how I've tried to get it working, but it still reverts to false even before the response has come in from the server. I don't understand how that's possible since onPostExecute should happen at the end (which is true for that toast)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you did there but what about something like:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(null);
```

sorry if I got your question wrong..